# Regex to not match url when contains certain word?

Tags: php, regex

I don't want my regex to match url's when they contain's `.premium-`.

And of course I have tried a lot of combinations found on this forum and others.

Most obvious this:

```
<a[^>]*href="(https://www.example.com/(?!\.premium\-)[^"']+)"[^>]*>
```

But that doesn't work. How should I do?

Comment: Are we processing a larger block of text or just `<a>` tags?  Care to offer a few samples and your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

### Brief

You're very close. You just missed `[^"']*`. Negative lookaheads are bound to the position you place it in the pattern, thus it won't look past that exact location in the string. You need to quantify *something* to tell it to look anywhere from that position on.

Also, you don't need to escape the `-` when it's not in a set, so using `\.premium-` will suffice.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/3kvTMQ/3)

```
<a[^>]*href="(https://www.example.com/(?![^"']*\.premium-)[^"']+)"[^>]*>
```

---

### Explanation

I simply added `[^"']*` at the forefront of your negative lookahead. This ensures it will continue as far as it needs to until the match (in the negative lookahead) is satisfied.